# I'm having trouble getting Razor statement to render a "UserOnProjectInRole" in my View in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, razor

I am having trouble getting a method extrapolated by the view to render an assigned user to a 'project'; the thing is I have an identical method in a different model/view/controller mechanism that is doing the exact same thing, with different users in different roles; just fine. I have a helper/controller for each and the model to controller and then to view is identical but one is not working; I have only two months coding experience so it's probably something simple my eye isn't seeing. I have checked DB and the AddUsersTo method is working, as the users appear on the correct table as being assigned; but for whatever reason they won't render in the view.

Here is the method in the helper

```
public string ListUsersOnProjectInRole(int projectId, string roleName)
{
    Projects projects = db.Projects.Find(projectId);
    switch (roleName)
    {

        case "Project Manager":
            if (projects.AssignedToUser == null)
            {
                return "Not Assigned";
            }
            return projects.AssignedToUser.DisplayName;

         default:
            return "Not Assigned";
    }
```

which is instanced via 'projectHelper' globally at the top of controller/view; and here is a snippet of the form in the view; the issue being the foreach loop.

```html
 <dt>
  @Html.DisplayName("Project Manager: ")
 </dt>
 <dd>
 @foreach (var user in projectHelper.ListUsersOnProjectInRole(Model.Id, "Project Manager"))
  {
    @user

  }
  </dd>
                                                           
      @using (Html.BeginForm("AddUserOnProject","Projects", FormMethod.Post))                               
                                    {
                                        if (User.IsInRole("Administrator"))
                                        {
                                            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                                            @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Id)
                                            
                                               
     <button type="submit" class="btn btn-outline-danger">SUBMIT</button>                                           
                              
                                        }
                                    }
```

Comment: For starters, connecting to the DB from the view is generally the wrong approach.  Everything to populate the model should happen in the controller, and the complete model should be sent to the view which just binds to that data.  (You should really never have to declare a variable in the view.)  Aside from that, how specifically is this failing?  What "doesn't work" about it?  When you step through the code in a debugger, which specific operation first produces an unexpected result?

Comment: That makes sense; I didn't know how to extrapolate a 'Listxyz on abc" method through the controller; I guess these methods are simple enough to just write IN the controller? (and since they are pulling from Db SHOULD be) that being said; When I am on a 'Projects' details view, I have a dropdown of 'Project Managers' and a submit button, the thing that isn't working is the foreach ie: listing after they've been assigned the project manager of that project. My developers to Tickets relationship and method is structured identically and is working as intended.

Comment: “Isn’t working” just isn’t a particularly specific problem description.  It’s time to use your debugger.  (If you haven’t used it before, this is the perfect time to start familiarizing yourself with it.  A debugger is a programmer’s most useful tool.)  Place a breakpoint in your helper method.  What values are being sent to it?  Are they what you expect?  What is returned?  Is it what you expect?  Why or why not?

Comment: And debugging offers no value in this instance as none of the operations are handling anything null; the tables in Db show them being assigned; they just aren't being shown in the List method afterwards; I have a switch statement which is producing the default "Not Assigned" value so it HAS to be being hit (and debugger brings back nothing either way)

Comment: could that inherently mean there is just something wrong with the way the switch is passing the data back?

Comment: “Debugging offers no value” - This is a categorically incorrect statement.  Debugging is how you examine the behavior of your code.  Refusing to do that is counterproductive.

Comment: I'm not refusing... I am debugging. I'm saying it's not giving me a lead to the error. :\ It hits the breakpoint and each variable being handled HAS a value and is NOT causing an error yet the method being evoked is NOT producing the results that an identical method IS.

Comment: *"HAS a value"* - What is the value?  Is it what you expect?  *"is NOT causing an error"* - A lack of exception is not an indication that the code works as expected.  An "error" is just as equally an unexpected result.  What is the specific unexpected result being produced by what specific input value?  *"NOT producing the results"* - What specific result is it producing?  What specific result was expected?  All I'm trying to do is get specific information, more detailed than simply "it's not working".  What are the specifics found while debugging?

Comment: okay I'm gonna put this in dumb blonde terms because again; two months IT experience in total. So please...I am trying to get a Project Manager : @user to render. when I debug and look at the DB, as far as I can tell the PM IS being assigned to the project as the DB table shows the correct values there; when I debug, the values are pulled back from DB like the methods are calling to do but the @ user statement in my view is not rendering them; it instead gives the default: "Not Assigned" result instead of the actual assigned Project Manager like I need and expected. What I'm confused about is

Comment: And this is why it's important to start practicing the use of a debugger.  If you place a debugging breakpoint inside your method that's producing an unexpected result, execution will pause on that breakpoint.  While it's paused you can examine the values of your variables.  You can then step through the code one line at a time in the debugger, and with each step examine the new values of your variables.  This will show you the exact behavior of your code.  This is the process you'd use to narrow down the specific point where the code does something different than you expect.

Comment: is the exact same method being called with developers is working. Should I just rewrite the method in the controller; instance the controller in the begin form and see if it renders? I'm not trying to be stupid but I don't have the language to extrapolate a lot of these issues so please don't crucify me. I'm learning. And I AM debugging. I don't understand if all values ARE not null and there are no errors thrown how debugging is of value here as it's not pointing me to where the error is.

Comment: It's most likely in the way I'm trying to call the method to list; as again all values as I can tell are present in db and variables when I debug. Sorry for any confusion.

Comment: *"I don't understand if all values ARE not null and there are no errors thrown how debugging is of value here"* - Perhaps an example... Suppose while paused in the debugger you observe that the value of `roleName` is `"Project Manager"`, but when stepping through the code you observe that the `switch` block moves to the `default` case.  That's a specific unexpected result, and that's something to ask about.  Or if you observe that the value is *not* `"Project Manager"` but you think it should be, that leads you to conclude that the unexpected result is elsewhere, meriting further debugging.